# razor pages: get value from enum

Tags: c#, razor, enums

Say I have this enum inside my Enums.cs class:

```
public enum JobBaseData
{
    Fulltime = 0,
    Parttime = 1,
    Internship = 2,
    Minijob = 3
}
```

Now I have my PageModel class which has an attribute which is

```
public JobBaseData BaseData { get; set; }
```

BUt inside my cshtml razor page I cannot do:

```
<input class="radiosize" type="radio" id="Vollzeit" name="rr" value="@Model.BaseData.FullTime" checked>
```

It does finde BaseData, but the static values dont exist on that model.

What I do NOT wanna do is to create a single Integer for every value inside the enum and access those:

```
public int FullTime {get; set;}
```

... and then set values to each variable inside the controller.

Is there a better way to access the valus from my enum inside my razor page that is not directly a member of the pagemodel but rather inside a different class?

Comment: _"But inside my cshtml razor page I cannot do: `@Model.BaseData.FullTime`"_ - uhm... that's not how `enum` types work in .NET - are you thinking of Java-style `enum` types (i.e. discriminated-union types)? If so, that's something entirely different (and C# doesn't support it either) - otherwie I'll admit I'm unsure what you're actually trying to do here...

Comment: Also, your `<input>` element doesn't seem to be using any Tag-Helpers at all...

Comment: hi, i already found an answer, please see below. But do explain what you mean with Tag-Helpers please :)

Comment: If you put `asp-for=""` then the `name=""` and `id=""` will be auto-generated to ensure form-model binding on POST succeeds (whereas with hand-written `name=""` attributes you need to manually update it every time you rename a form member or refactor your form/model types. See here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/input-tag-helper

Answer (score 0):

This was easier than I had thought:

For static enums:

do:

```
@using static XXX.Data.Helpers.Enums; // ur class where ur enums are
```

and then:

```
 value="@YourEnum.YourValue"
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "static enums" in .NET - and the `@using static` is entirely unnecessary here: you were apparently misunderstanding/misusing/conflating Razor's normal render syntax with form-binding attributes.

Comment: I dont really understand that, but for the purpose of what I am doing this totally works fine.